# Display store value in grid in ExtJS MVVM

Tags: javascript, mvvm, extjs

I'n new to MVVM and ExtJS both.

I have 2 stores: **People** and their **Duties**:

People: `['id', 'name','duty'],` where `duty` is an int key.

Duties: `['id', 'dutyName']`

#### I want to display people in grid, but in one column display not the duty id, but the duty name, e.g. not "1", but "Chef"

1) I've created a ViewModel.

```
Ext.define('TestApp.ViewModels.ListViewModel', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.ViewModel',
    alias: 'viewmodel.listVm',
    stores: {
        people: {
            type: 'PeopleStore',
            autoLoad: true
        },
        duties: {
            type: 'DutiesStore',
            autoLoad: true
        }
    },
```

2) Use this VM in View (Ext.grid.Grid)

```
viewModel: {type: 'listVm'},
    bind:
        {
            store: '{people}'
        },
```

3) Column with Duties  now contains ids ( '1', '2', '1' etc.)

```
{
            text: 'Должность',
            dataIndex: 'duty',
            flex: 2,
            valueId: 'id'
        }
```

Adding  `bind: {value: '{duties.dutyName}'}` and playing around throws errors `missing a setValue method`

Comment: What ExtJS version you use? What mean `valueId` property? I don't see it in documentation. `bind: {value: '{duties.dutyName}'} ` dont working because `column` has no value and getter and setter for it

Answer (score 0):

There may be a more elegant way to do this (would love to know if it exists) but I just use a custom renderer function in these cases. So your column definition would be something like:

```
   {
        text: 'Должность',
        dataIndex: 'duty',
        flex: 2,
        valueId: 'id',
        renderer: 'dutyColRenderer'
    }
```

And in your controller you'd do something like:

```
dutyColRenderer: function(dutyId){
    var dutyStore = this.getStore('duties'),
        dutyRec = dutyStore.getById(dutyId);

    return dutyRec ? dutyRec.data.dutyName : '';    
}
```